# Truecrypt read only Ubuntu

Tags: permissions, truecrypt

So i have an issue with Truecrypt after moving across from my Mac OSX. Treucrypt file container created in MacOSX, now living in my Ubuntu home folder.

Now when I mount my Truecrypt volume (asks for TC & Ubuntu administrator password) and tried to write anything to or within it it comes up as an error that the destination is read-only. Can read the files as normal.

I've checked the volume properties in Truecrypt, - it was NOT created as a read-only volume. 
When I mount the volume in Truecrypt for each session the 'Mount as read-only' option is NOT ticked.

I've a feeling this is an Ubuntu permissions issue or step that I'm missing. I've been mounting from the GUI.

Can anyone please enlighten me as to how to get write priveleges with the mounted container?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the file system used, this might help:

```
$ cd /media/truecrypt1
$ sudo chown -R $USER .
```

It sets the ownership of all files inside the encrypted file system to the currently logged in user.

Comment: I can confirm that this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I my case, I had to disable journaling on the Volume first. (I was mounting a fully-encrypted external hard-disk created on a Mac.)

On the Mac I did [as described here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110110060024871):

```
diskutil disableJournal /Volumes/myVolume
```

Afterwards I did what pcworld said. chown. Then it worked.